# Suggested tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Having just acquired enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms, I took a quick look through the list of tags.  I was able to successfully suggest one new synonym, but was unable to do so for other pairs.  Apparently, I haven't answered enough questions under these tags to qualify.  I think these tag synonyms are pretty straightforward, so I thought I'd post them here so someone else can create them.

- battery = batteries
- map = mapping
- wifi = wireless
- avr = atmega = atmel

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I just realized that on some level, requiring a score of 5 or more on a tag to create a synonym is a little silly.  Since the specified use is "common, alternate spellings or phrasings" for example “bike” for "bicycle", or “sock” for "socks".  So anyone with a grasp of the English language should be able to recognize these as the same.  Granted, there is some domain knowledge required for some synonyms (e.g. avr = atmega = atmel), but others are simply English (e.g. battery = batteries, and map = mapping).  Just an observation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ben, I have created tag synonyms for:

- [atmega](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmega) > [avr](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avr)
- [batteries](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) > [battery](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery)
- [map](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) > [mapping](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping)

The overlap between [wifi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) and [wireless](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) is minimal, since not all [wireless](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) communication is [wifi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi), and while all [atmega](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmega) are [avr](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avr), not all [atmel](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel) are.